# First immigrant generations and future generations

Tags: single-word-requests

Why is there no agreed definition for first generation immigrants and second generation? Is there a word for people of origins residing from a foreign country?

People who had ancestors from a different area start to forget their native culture and become accustom to their new culture.

I'm trying to find a word that replaces, " start to forget their native culture and become accustom to their new culture." Is there a better word?

Comment: Are you sure you only want single words? I think there is a controversy between "first-generation" and "second-generation immigrants", but these are the technical terms. Can you give a context where you would use that word?

Comment: @fev umm like second generation immigrants and beyond are less connected with their ancestors’ culture.

Answer (score 1):

The term you’re looking for may be *acculturation:*

> ac·cul·tur·a·tion  (ə-kŭl′chə-rāshən)
> n.
>
> 1. The modification of the culture of a group or individual as a result of contact with a different culture.
> 2. The process by which the culture of a particular society is instilled in a human from infancy onward.

Another term, less specific to culture, is *assimilation.*

There are many studies of immigration, acculturation, and how immigrant groups maintain their own cultures and language.